# Obtaining the SecurityIdentifier (SID) from just a domain username (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, security, active-directory

I wish to obtain the **domain** SID from a user account that has been used to access my web page, but...

In some instances, you **dont** have access to the HttpContext object to call `HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.User.Value`

All the static function is able to accept is a user-name as a string, and a domain-name as a string.

If the domain is left blank, it is amused that the user account name is within the same domain as the IIS server that the process is executing upon. :/

your help would be most appreciated as always.
Cheers.

Comment: It is true that HttpContext.Current will sometimes be null, but when specifically are you running into this issue?

Comment: this is a library function and should be able to be used when no HttpContext exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the a user's domain, you can use [LookupAccountName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  In case you need a pinvoke sample, get it from [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.LookupAccountSid)

You pass in `DOMAIN\UserName` to the function.  The `LookupAccountName` function will give you back the user SID and the domain name.

I suspect that you don't really need to know the domain SID.  I would think the returned domain name should be enough for you.  If you really want to know the domain SID, you can extract it directly from a the returned user SID.

A user SID is always starting with a domain SID.  For the details of how a SID structure looks like and how to extract the domain SID, please check [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962011.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Directory Services?  Need .Net 3.5 for this:

```
public UserPrincipal GetUserPrincipal(string userName)
    {            
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, LDAPDomain, LDAPUser, LDAPPassword);                     
        return UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName);            
    }
```

You can then use the UserPrincipal Class which has a .Sid method.

I set my Domain and AD account info from the web.config like so

```
private String LDAPDomain
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LDAPDomain"];
        }
    }
```